# Does it matter if my router is 802.11ac, but my wifi boosters are 802.11n?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, protocol

My Router is 802.11ac however my boosters are 802.11n. Will this affect the strength of the signal on my devices? Should I get boosters which have 802.11ac protocol?

Answer (score 2):

802.11ac is backwards compatible with 802.11n so it can work.

That said, wifi boosters are a bad technology - they waste a lot (like 50% of the bandwidth) - professionals would use another means (like cables or power over Ethernet) and deploy multiple access points on different non-overlapping frequencies.

Note that 802.11n gear has a greater range (thanks to beam forming and other multiple antenna tricks) so you may be able to get away with fewer boosters.

802.11ac boosters should significantly outperform 802.11n ones if you do decide to go that route.

Comment: If you have 802.11n boosters then any device that connects to them is connecting to a 802.11n network.  So basically your creating a 802.11n network on top of your 802.11ac network, so any 802.11ac device that connects to the 802.11n network you created, is limited by the 802.11n specifications